# Is it possible to copy fields from Sandbox to Production?

Tags: sandbox, fields, import, production

I have had to manually add 100+ fields (don't ask...) to a clients sandbox environment in order to test some updates.

However now that the testing seemed to be fine I am tasked with replicating all 100+ fields onto production which I would rather avoid if possible.

Is there is a way to export/import fields between environments?

Comment: change set(s) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [change set](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_changesets) to deploy fields from a sandbox to production.  First, in your Production org, go to "Deployment Settings" and edit your sandbox's deployment settings to allow inbound changes to Production. In your sandbox, go to "Outbound Change Sets," create a new one, and add all of your fields to it, then upload it to your Production org.  Back in your Production org, your change set will be available under "Inbound Change Sets" after it is processed.  If you don't have any Apex code, you'll be able to deploy it without worrying about test coverage.

Comment: Just make sure you add all the field dependencies for all custom fields

Comment: With fields, you'll want to make sure that you know how you're going to handle FLS and page layouts. If the profiles' permssions on the relevant fields are correct in the Sanbox, then you should include the profiles in the change set. If the fields are on page layouts, then you may want to send those as well, but note that any changes to the page layouts in production made since the sandbox was refreshed would be overwritten.

Comment: I almost always update page layouts manually, and usually do the same for permission sets unless I know I've never updated them since they were deployed.